# averaging every nth element of multiple lists

Tags: python, list, average

I have 4 lists of the same length and would like to average every nth element across the lists and make a new list out of these averaged values. As an example:

```py
y1 = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
y2 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 0]
y3 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y4 = [2, 1, 5, 7, 9]
```

The expected result should be:

```py
y1234  = [2, 3, 5, 7, 5]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "average every nth element"? Where does the "nth" part come into play?

Comment: @aaossa As in average of `y1[0]`, `y2[0]`, `y3[0]`, and `y4[0]` becomes the first element of `y1234`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4]).mean(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
y1 = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
y2 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 0]
y3 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y4 = [2, 1, 5, 7, 9]

n_lists = 4

y1234 = [int(sum(x)/n_lists) for x in zip(y1, y2, y3, y4)]
```

Note that in your example the last average would be 4.

`zip` returns a tuple that you can then send to the `sum`. Make sure that the conversion with `int` is what you want (not `round` or `floor` etc.)